# How to show multiple attributes while selecting items in v-autocomplete?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How do I achieve `v-autocomplete` to show both the value and text when selecting?

Here is my code-

```html
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="request"
    v-if="products.data"
    :items="products.data"
     outline
    chips
    label="Select item"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
     >
```

```js
products: [
   {
      text: "Apple",
      value: 209
   },
   {
      text: "Banana",
      value: 229
   }
]
```

Currently, I am able to display only the text but I want two display both (text and value in the options) before selecting.

Answer (score 2):

Using [slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#slots) you can do this-

```
<v-autocomplete
   :items="products"
   label="Select"
   item-text="text"
   item-value="value"
 >
  <!-- If you want to modify the selected data -->
   <template v-slot:selection="data">
     {{ data.item.text }} {{ data.item.value }}
   </template>

   <!-- If you want to modify the list options -->
   <template v-slot:item="data">
     {{ data.item.text }} {{ data.item.value }}
   </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```